# Select rows from a table matching other table records

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two SQL tables:

**items** table

```
item_id     name       timestamp
--------------------------------------------
a           apple      2014-01-01
b           banana     2014-01-06
c           tomato     2013-12-25
d           chicken    2014-01-23
e           cheese     2014-01-02
f           carrot     2014-01-16
```

**items_to_categories** table

```
cat_id      item_id
--------------------------------------------
1           a
5           c
2           e
3           a
4           f
5           d
5           b
5           a
```

Knowing `cat_id` (*eg 5*), I need to get 2 latest items (based on the `timestamp`) that belongs to that `cat_id`.

If I first get 2 rows from **items_to_categories** table:

```
SELECT item_id FROM items_to_categories WHERE cat_id = 5 LIMIT 2;
>> returns 'c' and 'd'
```

And then use returned items ids to query **items** table, I am not making sure returned items will be the latest ones (order by `timestamp`).

The ideal result what I need to get selecting 2 latest items by `cat_id` (*eg 5*) would be:

```
d           chicken    2014-01-23
b           banana     2014-01-06
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.item_id, t1.name, t1.timestamp 
   FROM items t1 
     LEFT JOIN items_to_categories t2 ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id 
       WHERE cat_id = 5 
       ORDER BY t1.timestamp DESC 
       LIMIT 2;
```

Use above query.

Comment: I would join items to items_to_categories rather than the way you have it, because the condition applies to items_to_categories, but +1 (despite unnecessary indentation)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT top 2 I.item_id, I.name, I.timestamp 
FROM items I 
JOIN items_to_categories IC ON I.item_id = IC.item_id 
WHERE IC.cat_id in (Select top 1 from items_to_categories order by timestamp desc)
ORDER BY I.timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT
items.item_id
items.item,
items.item_timestamp
FROM
items_to_categories
INNER JOIN items ON items_to_categories.item_id = items.item_id
WHERE
items_to_categories.cat_id = 5
ORDER BY items.item_timestamp desc
limit 2
```

By the way, timestamp is a reserved word, you really should avoid using it for a field name

Hope it will helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this using join to get the required result

```
SELECT a . * 
FROM items a
INNER JOIN items_to_categories b ON a.item_id = b.cat_id
ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC LIMIT 2
```